# How to solve incorrect syntax near 'xml'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error, ssms

I'm working on an administration program, and when writing one of it's features I encountered this error.

Here's the code.

CODE:

```
create procedure wIaTertiDemo 
    @sesiune varchar(50), 
    parXML xml
as
begin try
    declare @utilizator varchar(500)
    exec wIaUtilizator @sesiune @utilizator output

    select codfiscal, denumire as @dentert, adresa 
    from tertiDemo
    for xml raw

    --create table tertiDemo(codfiscal varchar(50), denumire varchar(500), adresa varchar(500)

end try
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @mesajEroare varchar(1000)
    SET @mesajEroare = ERROR_MESSAGE()+ '(' +OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ')'
    RAISERROR (@mesajEroare, 16,1)
END CATCH
```

Errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure wIaTertiDemo, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'xml'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure wIaTertiDemo, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@utilizator'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure wIaTertiDemo, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@dentert'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parXML xml
```

Should be:

```
@parXML xml
```

And

```
exec wIaUtilizator @sesiune @utilizator output
```

should be:

```
exec wIaUtilizator @sesiune, @utilizator output
```

And

```
denumire as @dentert
```

should be:

```
denumire as dentert
```

Comment: Much appreciated, tommorow when i get to work, I'll rewrite the parts from here and I'll let you know if i encounter any others problems.